# Writing from python to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the following to write the name and score to a text file. The name will write fine, but the score won't. Is there anything I have missed?

```
class Question:
     def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
          self.prompt = prompt
          self.answer = answer
print("General Quiz\n")
name = input("What's your name?")
print("Good Luck " + name + "!")
question_prompts = [
     "What is the capital of France?\n(a) Paris\n(b)London\n",
     "What color are bananas?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b)Yellow\n",
]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
]

def run_quiz(questions):
     score = 0
     for question in questions:
          answer = input(question.prompt)
          if answer == question.answer:
               score += 1
     print(name, "you got", score, "out of", len(questions))

run_quiz(questions)

file2write=open("testfile.txt",'a')
file2write.write(name + score)
file2write.close()
```

Comment: It would make more sense if your `run_quiz` function returned the score, and you capture the return value when you call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in here,

You must declare score outside the scope of the function, and use the global keyword inside the function to let the function know that you want to use the global version of the variable.

Also you need to cast score to a string

```
score = 0

class Question:
     def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
          self.prompt = prompt
          self.answer = answer
print("General Quiz\n")
name = input("What's your name?")
print("Good Luck " + name + "!")
question_prompts = [
     "What is the capital of France?\n(a) Paris\n(b)London\n",
     "What color are bananas?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b)Yellow\n",
]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
]

def run_quiz(questions):
     global score
     for question in questions:
          answer = input(question.prompt)
          if answer == question.answer:
               score += 1
     print(name, "you got", str(score), "out of", len(questions))

run_quiz(questions)



file2write=open("testfile.txt",'a')
file2write.write(name + str(score))
file2write.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

`score` is only scoped within the `run_quiz` function - you need to make it a global for it to be available in the penultimate line

Answer (score 2):

```
 class Question:
      def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
           self.prompt = prompt
           self.answer = answer
 print("General Quiz\n")
 name = input("What's your name?")
 print("Good Luck " + name + "!")
 question_prompts = [
      "What is the capital of France?\n(a) Paris\n(b)London\n",
      "What color are bananas?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b)Yellow\n",
 ]

 questions = [
      Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
      Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
 ]

 def run_quiz(questions):
      score = 0
      for question in questions:
           answer = input(question.prompt)
           if answer == question.answer:
                score += 1
      print(name, "you got", score, "out of", len(questions))
      return score 
 score = run_quiz(questions)

 file2write=open("testfile.txt",'a')
 file2write.write("\n{} {}".format(name, score))

 file2write.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `score` from function `run_quiz` 
like this

```
def run_quiz(questions):
 score = 0
 for question in questions:
      answer = input(question.prompt)
      if answer == question.answer:
           score += 1
 print(name, "you got", score, "out of", len(questions))
 return score

score = run_quiz(questions)
```

also make score `str` while writing `file2write.write(name + str(score))`

Answer (score 0):

Score is to be declared outside run_quiz function which will make it global to use.
Alternatively just return the value of Score ,the 2nd is better as having global variable dangling around is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Making a variable global enables it's use in any function (speaking generally).
The above statement can solve a lot of your problems while dealing with functions.